# Let $z_1,z_2$ solutions of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ and $b,c \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $z_1^{10}+z_2^{10} \in \mathbb C_R$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am an engineering student and I can't solve this problem. The drawback I have is how to work with the exponent 10. I know it is little I did but I have come this far:

**Problem:**

Let be $z_1,z_2$ solutions of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ and $b,c \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $z_1^{10}+z_2^{10} \in \mathbb C_R$

**Demonstration:**

If the roots are real, then $z_1^{10}+z_2^{10} \in \mathbb C_R$. End.

If one of the roots is complex, then the other is also complex and is its conjugate, by the Complex conjugate root theorem. (There cannot be a real root and a complex one). By Vieta's Formula, I have:

$z_1+z_2=-b$

$z_1z_2=c$

From here, I don't know how to continue. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Try to find $(z_1+z_2)^10$ with the binomial expansion and try to write it in terms of b and c.

Comment: Let $r_n=z_1^n+z_2^n$. Show that $r_n=-br_{n-1}-cr_{n-2}$. Note that $r_0=2$ and $r_1=-b$. What does this say about $r_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to compute $z_1, z_2$ or their powers explicitly. All you need is that the complex conjugate of a product is equal to the product of the complex conjugates (the complex conjugate is [“distributive” over addition, subtraction, multiplication and division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Properties)).

As you figured out, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are either both real numbers, or complex conjugates of each other, and you already solved it for the first case.

In the second case is
$$
 \overline{z_1^{10}} = \overline{z_1}^{10} = z_2^{10}
$$
so that $z_1^{10}$ and $z_2^{10}$ are also complex conjugates, and their sum is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand a bit on my earlier comment.

Let $r_n=z_1^n+z_2^n$. Since $z_k^n=-bz_k^{n-1}-cz_k^{n-2}$, we have
$$
r_n=-br_{n-1}-cr_{n-2}\tag1
$$
Note that $r_0=2$ and $r_1=-b$. Then, $(1)$ says that for all $n$,
$$
z_1^n+z_2^n=r_n\in\mathbb{R}\tag2
$$

Comment: Using [Newton's Identitites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), we can extend this to the sums of powers of all the roots of a polynomial (of any degree) with real coefficients.